# Как выделить конкретную строчку в таблице и вывести строкой?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хочу вывести последнюю строку таблицы отдельно.

Код `res1.iloc[9]` выводит просто значения списком, а мне нужно строкой так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как лучше сделать?

Comment: Пожалуйста, __никогда__ не приводите исходные данные картинками.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

передайте в `.loc[]` список вместо скаляра:

```
res1.iloc[[9]]
```

Comment: огонь!) спасибо))